# keras callback error with numpy broadcast

Tags: python, numpy, callback, keras

I'm using keras to build a rnn+dense model to realize siamese classifier and there is a operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,5) (6,5) (16,5) error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/prog/COQA/project/classify_question_with_siamese_drei.py", line 
122, in <module>
    classifier.model.fit([question1, question2, is_same], y=None, 
batch_size=16, epochs=1)
  File "C:\Users\Joker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1657, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\Joker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1219, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_batch_end(batch_index, batch_logs)
  File "C:\Users\Joker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 109, in on_batch_end
     callback.on_batch_end(batch, logs)
  File "C:\Users\Joker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 216, in on_batch_end
     self.totals[k] += v * batch_size
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,5) 
(6,5) (16,5)
```

It seems to be something wrong with the keras callback on_batch_end, and I have the training data size 2566 and batch_size 16, which means the (6,5) is the last part of the data.
When I further explore the error and find that in the callbacks.py where the broadcast problem occurs:

```
self.totals[k] += v * batch_size
```

here the normal v is a [16,5] array and when the error occured, it become [6,5], I was wondering what's wrong here.
Besides, the model take 3 inputs, the x1 x2 and the label, attention that label is in the input because the loss function will use it.

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the input shape of the data and your network? What kind of keras callbacks did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the first dimension of Input layer with specific batch_size or other number?

e.g. `x_in = Input(shape=(4, num_feature))` may result in this error (`4` is batch_size in my own case), and when I changed it to `x_in = Input(shape=(None, num_feature))`, this error disappear.